# Contextual filter by author id

Tags: 7, views

Ok, so here's my problem. I feel it's really very simple and I am missing something. I have a Drupal 7 view which shows a certain type of content. Say it has a url `mysite.com/article`. What I want is, if the url is like `mysite.com/article/me`, it would load the articles posted by this current user. "me" will always be "me" and would not take any id/username.

Hope the problem is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing one of the buried options.

- Make a view, configure it the way you need.
- Make a **Page** display, and set the path to article/me
- Add a **Relationship** for **Content: Author**.  This is likely not needed, unless you want to pull in author fields and display them or if you need the author name explicitly somewhere in another filter.
- Add a **Contextual Filter** for **Content: Author uid**; it should automatically pick up the relationship.  In the options for **When the filter value is *not* available**, select **Provide default value**.  In the dropdown, choose **User ID from logged in user**.

I think you are missing the last part of the final step.  I always forget where that one is.  It helps if you configure views to always show the advanced settings (see admin/structure/views/settings).

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks MPD, your answer provided the solution. I am just re-iterating the same here in case anyone else needs

What I did was

- create a view with two separate pages, one having the url `mysite.com/articles` and the other `mysite.com/articles/me`
- In the "me" page I simply added a contextual filter on author:uid (didnt need the relationship as it comes by default) and gave a default value of "User ID from from logged in user" for filter not being present in the url and made that for the "me" page only.
- As for the original without "me" page, which will also extend the contextual filter of the "me" page, we need to set the filter not being present in the url to "Display all results for the specified field" and make it "All displays (except overriden)".

Bingo!!! your view is ready now. Hope I explained myself clearly, and thanks again to MPD.